# how to wrap image without using div element?

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a div element but I want to wrap this image inside the div but without using another div which element should I use .

Comment: Can you please explain what do you meant by wrap, can you share the code

Comment: @Ahmed When you say 'wrap inside the div' do you mean you want the image to fit the div? Please add your code and try to further explain what you mean